# Regex in bash scripting

Tags: regex, bash, shell

I have 2 similar files names that need to go into different directories. I tried using the following regex.

- File 1: `abc_xyz_2016_12_02.out`
- File 2: `abc_xyz_test_2016-12-02.out`

Regex used:

```
regex_abc_xyz="abc_xyz_[0-9]{1,4}-[0-9]{1,2}-[0-9]{1,2}.out"
regex_abc_xyz_test="abc_xyz_test_[0-9]{1,4}-[0-9]{1,2}-[0-9]{1,2}.out"
```

`regex_abc_xyz` works but `regex_abc_xyz_test` is failing.

Comment: Filename wildcards are not regular expressions.

Comment: How are you using these regular expressions? Show your script.

Comment: Sidenote here but `.` should be escaped so that it's literal. `.` in regex means "any character". Doesn't break your regex, but just so that you know for the future.

Comment: How does `regex_abc_xyz_test` fail?  What is the error message?

Comment: You could make the `test_` optional with `(test_)?`

Answer (score 0):

Using your example test strings (the first of which I assume was mistyped, using underscores between the date components instead of hyphens), I entered these together with your regular expressions into [RegEx 101](http://regex101.com).  Both matched the appropriate filenames.

As one user stated, you ought to escape your period, i.e. `\.out`, but otherwise, your regular expressions are fine.

However, if all you need is to separate two lots of files into two different directories, and each begin with a fixed string (I’m implying this given your regex patterns that start with `abc_xyz` and `abc_xyz_test`), then could you not use a wildcard expression to move the latter group first, then the remaining group second ?

So:

```
mv abc_xyz_test*.out /path/to/new/folder/
```

Then:

```
mv abc_xyz*.out /path/to/new/folder/
```